# How to make people understand that I am working in a part of my vast domain

Tags: conversations, awkward-situations

I am a Telecommunications engineer who's been working as a programmer these days. One of my dreams was to continue my master degree and become a control system engineer. I always read about the subject and learn the math and science behind this domain.

Despite my explanation that programming is a tiny subset of the engineering field (from Assembly to vanilla Javascript or Arduino language or ...), people keep asking me:

> OH NO, you are not working in your domain and with an NGO who may left and end your contract when there's no fund anymore!!! How bad is that.
>   OH NO, you're 27 years old, why don't you find another job in engineering?

How can I told people that programming is a part of 90% of engineering field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to determine if the people ask such questions because they are genuinely worried or because they want to put you down.

In the first case then you should dispel doubts by explaining what you really want to do, how it broadens your job chances and could result in a bigger wage. Explain that you may not earn 1K a month for 10 years but 150K in one year.

Otherwise, if the person asking just wants to guilt trip you and make you feel miserable, say that 27 is very, VERY young. Just say that [Brian May](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brian_May) was 59 when he re-registered for his PhD.

To solve your own doubts: I was 29 years old when I went back to college to study what I wanted. I was 32 years old when I changed my job to earn twice as much as I did previously and moved to new city. There are envious people who just want to project their own fears on you.